# how to used if else with for loop in pandas data Frame with Column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am having an csv (code.csv) file which contains some words/data available in rows. in columns 'A' and I want to count that words in  a text file (data.txt) and want to print count in txt file (test.txt). with words which is at least came 1 time. if word is not available in excel don't print. but counter printing all words including which is not available in text with 0 count. so in for loop i want to use if else statement. someone can help me.
I have tried...

```
`import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("code.csv", delimiter=None, header=None, index_col = False)
df.columns = ['A']
df.dropna(subset = ["A"], inplace=True)
df['A'] = df['A'].astype('string')


with open('data.txt', 'r') as txtfile:
    test_string = txtfile.read()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    counter = test_string.count(row['A'])
    print(row['A'], ': ' + str(counter), file=open("test.txt", "a"))
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply apply a for loop on column A for each word and search for it in the string as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
df.columns = ['A']
df.dropna(subset = ["A"], inplace=True)
df['A'] = df['A'].astype('string')

with open('data.txt', 'r') as txtfile:
    test_string = txtfile.read()

output = ''
for word in df['A']:  
  if word in test_string:
    print(word, '\t', test_string.count(word))
    # words and their count in a string
    output += str(word) + ' \t ' + str(test_string.count(word)) + '\n'
  
# writing to output file
with open('test.txt', 'w') as outputfile:
    outputfile.write(output)
```